# Elasticsearch- Single Index vs Multiple Indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have more than 4000 different fields in one of my index. And that number can grow larger with time.
As Elasticsearch give default limit of 1000 field per index. There must be some reason.

Now, I am thinking that I should not increase the limit set by Elasticsearch.
So I should break my single large index into small multiple indexes.

Before moving to multiple indexes I have few questions as follows:

1. The number of small multiple indexes can increase up to 50. So searching on all 50 index at a time would slow down search time as compared to a search on the single large index?
2. Is there really a need to break my single large index into multiple indexes because of a large number of fields?
3. When I use small multiple indexes, the total number of shards would increase drastically(more than 250 shards). Each index would have 5 shards(default number, which I don't want to change). Search on these multiple indexes would be searching on these 250 shards at once. Will this affect my search performance? Note: These shards might increase in time as well. 
   When I use Single large index which contains only 5 shards and a large number of documents, won't this be an overload on these 5 shards?

Comment: How come you have so many fields? What’s your use case?

Comment: How much data are we talking about? Do you have 50GB of Data or 5TB?
Also: Do you have one index containing everything or do you rotate Indices daily/weekly/on another schedule?

Comment: @AtlandaGonazol Data is maximum 10gb. It is not my main concern. Neither I rotate my data.               Now, I have only one index with too many field, which I think can lead to mapping explosion.

Answer (score 0):

1. It strongly depends on your infrastructure. If you run a single node with 50 Shards a query will run longer than it would with only 1 Shard. If you have 50 Nodes holding one shard each, it will most likely run faster than one node with 1 Shard (if you have a big dataset). In the end, you have to test with real data to be sure.
2. When there is a massive amount of fields, ES gets a performance problem and errors are more likely. The main problem is that every field has to be stored in the cluster state, which takes a toll on your master node(s). Also, in a lot of cases you have to work with lots of sparse data (90% of fields empty).
3. As a rule of thumb, one shard should contain between 30 GB and 50 GB of data. I would not worry too much about overloading shards in your use-case. The opposite is true.

I suggest testing your use-case with less shards, go down to 1 Shard, 1 Replica for your index. The overhead from searching multiple Shards (5 primary, multiply by replicas) then combining the results again is massive in comparison to your small dataset.

Keep in mind that document_type behaviour changed and will change further. Since 6.X you can only have one document_type per Index, starting in 7.X document_type is removed entirely. As the API listens at _doc, _doc is the suggested document_type to use in 6.X. Either move to one Index per _type or introduce a new field that stores your type if you need the data in one index.